# How to represent a NSnumber with a zero in its left side?

Tags: ios

I am converting a string to NSnumber but when i do so,the zero in the left side of the number is omitted. For example the string is "09" when i convert it to Nsnumber it becomes 9. How can i get xcode to represent 09 as a NSnumber?

Comment: That does not make sense. `9` and `09` are exactly the same numbers. Only when you convert the number to a string, you can choose to display leading zeros.

Comment: There is a difference between a number and a string of decimal digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modify its string representation:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSNumber *i = @9;
        NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", i.intValue];
        NSLog(@"%@",s);
    }
}
```

Comment: not every String that i read is supposed to have a zero in its left side! with this code obviously you are adding a zero manually. when the string is "18" you get 018" with this.but i only wanna get a zero behind it when its a one digit number.

Comment: @RashidAsgari: *"... with this code obviously you are adding a zero manually"* - No. You should try (and understand!) the code before jumping to conclusions.

Comment: @RashidAsgari - Look at the documentation for `printf`, and, in particular, the standard format tokens for describing how data should be formatted.  There is a lot of power there.  (Objective-C uses the `printf` scheme with a few extensions.)

Comment: is there a way not to add the 0 to the string but the actual number?

Comment: no as martin said above... 9 IS 09 . only the string can differ